# RxJS (and Angular): Attempting to cache one-time HTTP requests still causes multiple requests

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm still in the process of getting comfortable with RxJS, so this is potentially an easy question.

Currently I am attempting to lazily make an XHR request for some data that I only need to fetch once and then cache indefinitely while the page is open, and I think I'm on the right track by trying to leverage an `AsyncSubject` with the value emitted from Angular's HTTP client. What I have so far basically looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
class AuthService {
     user$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
     // do .switchMap() so we reset when the auth'ed user changes
     extraInfo$ = this.user$.switchMap(() => {
         return this.http.get('/api/account').share();
     });

     constructor(http: HttpClient) { }
     ...
}
```

This almost works since the request isn't made until something subscribes to `extraInfo$`, and `.share()` should prevent additional requests being made when I have more than 1 observer on it.

However, if I unsubscribe to it and `extraInfo$` becomes cold (since there are 0 subscribers), subscribing to it again causes an additional request to be made again.

Right now I'm tempted to override the `._subscribe()` property on an `AsyncSubject` so that I can run the request when it gets its first observer, but that feels a bit too hackish.

Comment: I see `BehaviorSubject`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform a request and then cache the result for this on any subsequent subscription, you can do this a lot easier:

```
@Injectable()
class AuthService {
     user$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

     extraInfo$ = this.user$.switchMap(() => {
         return this.http.get('/api/account').shareReplay(1);
     });

     constructor(http: HttpClient) { }
     ...
}
```

By using `shareReplay(1)` you are fixing the problem you had with the `share` operator. They are both multicasting operators but with different properties. You want the operator to be repeatable and not retryable (checkout this article I wrote on the subject to help you http://blog.kwintenp.com/multicasting-operators-in-rxjs/ understanding what I mean).

Just remember, If you want to cache a certain observables result indefinitely, `shareReplay` is the one you need.

Comment: Thank you! Your article was helpful too. That does help get rid of the intermediate `BehaviorSubject` I ended up using.

Comment: However, I still have the issue of the function passed to `.switchMap()` running when the observable becomes hot again. I would think that doing `.switchMap(...).shareReplay(1)` would also fix that problem, but it doesn't seem to be work.

Comment: Just a little tweak: `extraInfo$ = this.user$.switchMapTo(this.http.get('/api/account').shareReplay(1))`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something eventually, the following works for what I need:

```
const lastFetchedInfo = new WeakMap();

@Injectable()
class AuthService {
   user$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
   // do .switchMap() so we reset when the auth'ed user changes
   extraInfo$ = this.user$.switchMap(user => !user ? Observable.empty() : new Observable((observer) => {
     if (!lastFetchedInfo.has(user)) {
       const subject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
       lastFetchedInfo.set(user, subject.filter(o => o !== null));
       this.http.get('/api/account').subscribe(info => subject.next(info));
     }
     const subscription = lastFetchedInfo.get(user);
     return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
   }));

   constructor(http: HttpClient) { }
   ...
}
```

I decided to use a `BehaviorSubject` instead of `AsyncSubject`since I can expand to set intervals on refreshing the data from here if I need to.